# Error in define class above Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

When I define class above the windows forms class computer shows this message:
The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.

How to solve this?? I used the objects of my class in the windows forms class.

Comment: Do what it asks you to do?

Comment: Did you... read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is telling you to move upward the code of `Form1` to be the first class in the file. Just do it, and VS will be happy again.

Don't worry about ordering of classes. C# is not C++, and does not care about ordering.

Comment: The question was flagged C++, so ordering of classes does matter.

Comment: @JoshStribling what you say is true, but on the other hand what OP is describing is from WinForms C#. I have seen it. Seeing as OP didn't come back I guess he got the answer one way or the other.

Comment: Ah, sorry when I hit enter to start a new line it posted the comment, I was going to say that I just ran into this issue with some old C++ & WinForms code.  I had to comment out the forward declarations of the other classes to get the designer to load, then reverted the comments